# Rails undefined method `sections' for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A Page has_many Section so that a Section belongs_to Pages. So if I want to retrieve all the "sections" of a Page I should write it like that "Page.sections" but I have an error.

```
2.0.0-p353 :042 > pages = Page.where(id: 48)
Page Load (0.4ms) SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 48
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Page id: 48, name: "---\n- français\n", parent_id: 36, created_at: "2014-01-22 00:33:48", updated_at: "2014-01-22 00:33:48">]>
2.0.0-p353 :043 > section = Section.where(page_id: 48).count
(0.3ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sections` WHERE `sections`.`page_id` = 48
=> 3
2.0.0-p353 :044 > pages.sections
NoMethodError: undefined method `sections' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Page:0x00000004f53c60>
...
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Show us the model code.

Comment: on Page i have this :  `has_many :sections, dependent: :nullify`
and on Section  `belongs_to :page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a collection of pages. When you use

```
Page.where(id: 48)
```

You are getting an array returned to you. What you want to do is

```
Page.find 48
```

This will return only one element. In which case you should be able to use your `sections` method with no problems.

If for some reason, you want to use `.where`, you can use something like

```
pages.first.sections
```

to retrieve the sections of the FIRST element in the list (when you use `where` with `id`, you should only get a single element in your array)

Comment: Thks! It's working. I did `pages = Page.find 48` than I did `pages.sections.first`. Instead of `pages.first.sections` thks!